# Root full on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: xubuntu

After installing some operating system updates my root partition is full. I'm a new user of UBUNTU so I'm sure this is an easy fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Comment: ... or is that /boot ?

Answer (score 0):

First find the directory that has used most of your hard disk space by running
`# du -sh /*`.

Let assume it is `/var` dir.

Now you could add additional hard disk & create a brand new partition on it by running
`# fdisk /dev/sdb` (here it is assumed the newly connected hard disk is `/dev/sdb`)

Let assume the created partition is `/dev/sdb1` and it is formated with ext4 filesystem.

Now, let the system /var dir's mount point is to be that partition

- edit the /etc/fstab with your favorite editor (nano or vi)
- add the following and save it and reboot to see the effected changes
- /dev/sdb1  /var  ext4 default 0 0