# Unable to update my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, software-sources

I am trying to update the ubuntu by `root@sachin-verma: sudo apt-get update`
It ignores all the packages like:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release 
......                            
Get:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]                             
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                        
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]          
Err:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [709 kB]
....
Get:78 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.3 kB]   
Ign:78 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons             
.... 
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
....'
```

My sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

I am using the network provided by my company, Please help me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` ignores all the packages from some of the links in your question because `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` is a broken link and this broken link does not have a release file. In general the instructions for solving a `does not have a release file` error are found at [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/).

1. I might be wrong, but I think there is a file named *getdeb.list* in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory that has broken links to software sources from getdeb.net in it. If it isn't in getdeb.list, search for it in other files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. Comment out all lines containing `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list` by preceding them with a `#` character. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list
   ```

   After commenting out all lines containing `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list` press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in getdeb.list, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit from nano text editor.
2. Remove 50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist file.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist
   ```
3. Remove getdeb.list.bck file.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck
   ```
4. Fix the `NO_PUBKEY` error by following the instructions in [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/).
5. Run the following command to update the list of available software:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
6. Your root ( `/` ) is currently 100% used up, so you need to free up space in `/` in order to do much of anything including running `sudo apt update`. Refer to the question: [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/). Your `/` partition is only 19GB instead of the recommend size of at least 25GB. Allocating at least 50GB for `/` partition is more like it. [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/) Or fresh install Ubuntu 18.04 and allocate at least 50GB to the `/` partition.
7. If the first 6 steps are any indication you may have totally hosed your system with numerous other errors that you haven't found yet, but because this is a company computer maybe your company will decide to let it remain there uselessly without reinstalling Ubuntu. The next time you need to connect to the internet from work you can use your phone. Maybe if you explain the situation to your company's tech support, they will understand and reinstall Ubuntu or let you install Ubuntu 18.04 and try again. I'm assuming that the management of your company would rather see you install Ubuntu 18.04 which takes about 30 minutes than have you spend days at your desk trying to repair what's already broken.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see  `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` in  my source.list- https://pastebin.com/7QSLTp36

Comment: @Karen, Thanks you very much, I have cleaned some space, It is working now, If problem persist, then I will install 18.04.