# Automatic zipping and archival of older logs

Tags: command-line, zip

As my disk space is less , i would need to zip and archive the logs in another directory which are older than 30 days.

Can someone please modify the below command to zip the 30 days older files and move it to destination folder.

```
find . -name 'server.log*' -mtime +30 -exec zip -r /home/user/Logs/ /opt/apps/log {} \;
```

where `server.log` is a log file and there will be many logs with datestamp attached like this `server.log_290719`.
`/home/user/Logs` is destination folder and `/opt/apps/log` is source folder.

Comment: You should look into [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: As @Jobs : logrotate does gzip old logs. But it does not move archives. You should run `sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` then move `gz` created files. FYI there are some other files taking a lot of  space on root partition. Think snap old packages, old kernels and apt cache See https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/77093

Comment: @jos Logrotate doesn't work very well with filenames that aleady have a timestamp in their name, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962477/logrotate-files-with-date-in-the-file-name