# Boot Issue - Constant Prompt to log in [18.04]

Tags: 18.04

I have this issue with my dual boot laptop (Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04):

I logged in Ubuntu, initially, without a huge issue, and was trying to download a file via Chrome, which failed due to a full disk error. Foolishly, I replied to this by rebooting the system and then all hell broke loose, as my computer couldn't boot into Ubuntu, constantly displaying a black screen with information on the boot process and being stuck on "Started hold until boot process finishes up". This, according to the internet, means my disk is indeed very full, which lead me to running Ubuntu recovery mode, selecting "clear" in an attempt to free up space, which didn't automatically free up anything. Next, I booted recovery > root and uninstalled a few packages I didn't need. After rebooting normally, I was prompted to enter my password on the Ubuntu Login UI, which I did successfully but my computer kept me logged out, again asking for the password.

I'm stuck, what do I do? Is there a safe way to add space to my linux partition through windows without destroying everything? Thank you.

Comment: Logging into GUI requires temporary work files to be created in $HOME, if there is insufficient space for those files, the login fails and you return to the login prompt (without error message, ie. a login loop).  You can however login via text terminal (no work files required) to create more space.  Once sufficient space exists in $HOME (your user directory), GUI logins will proceed.  This is one possible issue you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/57994/)

Comment: Guiverc yes that is the issue as I get it but I am not sure as to how to fix it aka free up space without destroying my dual boot basically. Karel I did check the first link you said but didn't help, so I made another post, I'll see if the second fixes it, otherwise I'll keep this post open. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache with `apt-get clear` made it all work, thankfully.