# 250GB root partition is getting full at 50GB

Tags: partitioning

I've partitioned root to have 250gb, all the space available on my ssd. For some reason it's "filling up", i.e. I can't make use of TAB when filling paths or commands in the terminal. I must've configured something wrong and I am in need of pointers where to begin fixing this.

Below is a screenshot of a samba share that's mounted at /docker.

[image: samba share viewed from win10]

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/77093

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't unfortunately fix the 250GB ssd mounted at root appear as 50GB