# Filesystem root low disk space

Tags: filesystem, root, disk-usage

I guess this is probably some bug, but my system has been complaining about low disk space since yesterday, and it halts the execution of some scripts that I run as a result. However, the disk with my root is far from being full. It's a 8 TB disk and almost 3 TB are empty. Here is the output of `df`.

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             65932236          0   65932236   0% /dev
tmpfs            13193628      59176   13134452   1% /run
/dev/sda2      7751335268 5173493328 2187174268  71% /
tmpfs            65968136    1041112   64927024   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            65968136          0   65968136   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            13193628        100   13193528   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc       7752327804 3879849672 3481760420  53% /mnt/disk2
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and managed to solve it or does anyone have any idea what could I do?

Comment: Please include the output of `df -i` as well, as this will show number of free inodes.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/77093

Comment: You can also be out of space if you have no inodes available too; ie. loads of tiny files using almost no disk space, but have used all 'blocks/inodes' created at format time.   If you want to use the extra space - you can use it by growing files (or erasing some of your possibly hundreds of thousands of tiny files that may have used all inodes allocated at format time)

Comment: If possible, show us the complete, exact error you are seeing