# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on « started waiting until snapd is fully seeded », keyboard not responding

Tags: boot, 18.04, disk-usage, reboot, boot-repair

I started getting « No Space Left on Disk » errors , despite having plenty of disk space. I initially dealt with this by doing « export TMPDIR=/home/new_tmp_path, but this only fixed some things not all. For example print screen wouldn’t work (probably because it relies on tmp space, which for some reason it thought was not available).
I decided to reboot my computer, and now it’s stuck on this msg:

/dev/sda5: clean, 2201825/7790592 files, 29739750/31133440 blocks.

[ OK ] started snapd deamon.

started waiting until snapd is fully seeded...

The keyboard is active when the Ubuntu logo displays at the beginning of the boot, but as soon as it shows the Snapd msg the keyboard is not responsive. I can’t enter any commands to debug or do anything !
Please help !

Comment: There is not enough information to know what's causing the problem. Do you have access to a Linux live USB, or to another computer to create one? If so, please boot from this and post the result of `df -h`. This will give us an idea of your disk and partition layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 0):

I used a Linux live USB per @Kurankat 's suggestion. Turns out docker had filled up my root. cleaned it and now things are back to normal.