# Cannot login (login loop), I tried multiple solutions. + no space left

Tags: 18.04, login, xfce, disk-usage

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Xfce4. I have a very low-end computer and the storage size is very low, only 60GB. I almost stay at a few 100MB from the limit.

But now, my computer lagged so I forced to reboot, then I got the endless login loop thing. I pressed CTRL+ALT+F3 and I ran the command `df -h`
I got as result that my disk was full at 100% and I got no byte left.

Then I tried to remove things, I am pretty sure I removed over than 300MB but it still says that I got 0 byte left. I tried it with different users but nothing works.

I tried to change the permissions of *.Xauthority* *.ICEauthority* and */tmp* but these perms are correct.

Then I tried to install "lxdm" but I couldn't because I don't have the space left.

Please help me, I don't know what to do I cannot use my computer. : /

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space) and [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/859630/)

Comment: What is 04 LTS ?

Comment: If the problem is space, changing permissions of files could just make it worse. A GUI requires space in $HOME (your user directory), and will abort the login & return you to the greeter (no messages, ie. login loop) if insufficient space is required (the GUI couldn't start), but that won't stop your text terminals from logging in to explore & create some space. Login via terminal & check you have space in $HOME (/home/$USER) and don't try and install anything when space is limited (it risks corrupted files due to space & makes issues worse)

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, I misspell I meant Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instead. But interesting fact to know!

Comment: @guiverc Also I tried to do that but as I said I removed hundreds of megabytes and it still says that 0 bytes left. I don't understand that, because the files are not put into trash in these cases.

Comment: @SorenA Sorry, I misspell I meant Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instead. But interesting fact to know!

Comment: @karel I will look after your first link, but I removed space and ran commands similar as these ones (apt clean, etc) but it doesn't change the number and stays at 0  bytes left

Comment: If you're worried about removing files & not seeing the space being freed, I'd stop using the system asap & switch to a *live* system & `fsck` your disk/partition from there, and do changes there. A lack of space can mean some background jobs are *zombie* waiting for space for them to work, when space is available they'll continue processing & instantly use the space, so when space is that low, it can be a little annoying. Maintain your system & keep say ~1GB safety margin (you'll need more come *release-upgrade* time though)

Comment: @guiverc Yeah I think I learnt a lesson here. What is fsck? Also, do you think Snap stuff have a link with zombie processes? I was trying to create a snap package before it failed. And snap is also always slowing down the startup and poweroff of the computer.So I start to get somewhat suspicious about it...

Comment: `fsck` is the *file-system check* command which checks for, and fixes any logical errors on your file-system. FYI: I have a 27GB / partition, and my /home is 31GB (though I store most my files on network storage & not locally) so 60GB is fine, but you still need to watch for space issues (I know that from experience)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111574/discussion-between-chopin-and-guiverc).

Comment: Sorry I'm accessing the site via Ubuntu SSO & thus not logged into SE itself. Chat is a Stack Exchange service I cannot access via Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, I am not using askubuntu often so I just clicked on the link... About fsck : I can't run it logged in right? I need to run it with another medium?

Comment: Most file-systems are best if they are checked (`fsck`) whilst umounted.. which is why I suggested a *live* system (your disk file-systems won't be used).  I wouldn't expect problems (I suspect it's zombie/tasks waiting for disk space to be free so they can continue, log entries of out-of-disk-space warnings being written/queued to be written etc) but if it's not - unexpected reducing disk space can be a warning sign telling you to `fsck` asap.

Comment: @guiverc Unfortuately I cannot do it using a live disk. My USB is not recognized in the BIOS. I already got something like that in the past but here It requires a password to access to the BIOS, and I forgot it :/

Comment: You can install/clone an ISO to a partition on your hdd/ssd, so `grub` will let you select and boot it from `grub`, likewise use another installed system you boot, but to `chroot` to another system isn't easy, and you still need another system to `chroot` into. Your issue though is space, so use the text terminal to fix that, and `touch /forcefsck` to force your system to `fsck` next boot.

Answer (score 0):

About what was taking the storage, it was the data from the snap package "multipass" which I removed, but the data was still there. 10GB of data for a package I never used! I don't understand where it's coming from xD

To solve the issue tho, it wasn't just the "0 byte left" that was creating the login loop. I don't know the source of this issue. But I simply backup everything and install Xubuntu instead.

Thanks to everybody who answered, these are still interesting things to know : )