# Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root", Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, root, disk-usage

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.1`.
While installing Ubuntu for the Desktop, I read that **15-20 GB** is more than enough for `Filesystem root`.

But now I am facing this error:

```
Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"
The volume "Filesystem root" has only 1.1 GB disk space remaining.
```

I tried all of the previous solutions. Unable to resolve this, without losing my data.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about Ubuntu Desktop, Server or something else, but the recommended minimum for Ubuntu Desktop has been 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
Still exploring ways to expand the size of my root home.
:-/

Comment: What exactly does "*I tried all of the previous solutions*" mean? What exactly did you try?

Comment: I tried cleaning cache and other temp folders. But something is logged up in my system. 
The last thing will be trying to increase my Filesystem root(trying to avoid that, as this issue was not coming previously, after running some docker commands, this comes up)

Comment: see this : https://askubuntu.com/a/1161181/77093