# QUESTION NS-3 ubuntu

Tags: apt, wireless, 20.04

I want to ask if anyone work with the simulator NS-3?, actually I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 and I wanted to download NS-3.31, but during the building phase, it compiles and then it shows an error `build failed`

[image]

I don't know to fix this issue.

Comment: My French is not good, but that looks like a simple lack of free disk space rather than a problem with NS-3 specifically

Comment: Does this answer your question ("No space is available on the device")? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)