# Ubuntu reports low disk space, but I can't find where it is

Tags: disk-usage

I have Ubuntu running on a virtualbox VM. When I start Ubuntu, it reports "Low Disk Space". But when I check my partitions, I don't see where.
I have a 2GB Swap partition and `/` is a 14GB partition with 2.5GB free space. When I run an update, it is as:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I've also tried using bleachbit, but I still get the error.
[image]

Comment: The recommended minimum disk allocation has been 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 (or all releases using GNOME Shell) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements, so you need to watch your usage given you've chosen to use less space.  I'd suggest using `du` (disk usage) to narrow down & consider increasing size of your partition to recommended minimum.   (yes many users & bloggers get by on less; but they *nuke & install* rather than *release-upgrade*, don't add many packages etc..)

Comment: The notification is "low disk space" but the details say 0 bytes remaining. Once your root file system runs completely out of space it can become easily corrupted.  The closet analogy is suffocation.  You may need to reinstall the OS.  Consider a dynamic container size with a large enough maximum size so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 2):

probably your /boot has too many kernel versions

first get all kernel list:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1
```

the result would be sth like:

```
linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-62-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-65-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-66-generic
```

then delete just old kernels:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic
```

and delete unused packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: The OP's output does not show a separate /boot partition to fill with older kernels.

Comment: True. I used to have one, then thought, "Why bother! It's a VM."  But it's also not a bad suggestion. :)