# Resize Ubuntu partition without losing data?

Tags: disk-usage

I've searched on the web but didn't find any clear answer or way to do this.

This is my disk usage:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c49Cc.png

These are my partitions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqpO.png

I have 160GB and want to resize vda1 partition without losing data.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: The question "without loosing data" should never be asked. ANY change in the partitions has that risk, ranging from very small to severe depending on the actual operation and the drive's health. BACKUPS is what you should have no mater what.

Comment: @ChanganAuto nop

Comment: If the situation has gotten so bad that `/` has 0 Bytes remaining, you will probably have to reinstall the OS. This is typically fatal.  That is the bad news.  The good news is that it's very easy to simply reformat the disk and repartition before cleanly reinstalling Ubuntu. Be sure to give your Ubuntu partition enough space so that it does not run out of space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score -1):

To increase the size of the partition you are going to have to slide the partitions that follow to provide a gap to fill.

If you have no partition to delete and no free space you'll need a larger disk. The original is then your backup.

Then increase the partition size, and (important) grow the file system to fill the new size.

Your partition is full? Boot a live distro or GParted to sort this.