# How can I fix these broken dependencies? No free space error -

Tags: upgrade, updates, dpkg, dependencies, disk-usage

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
linux-headers-generic : Depende: linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic pero no está instalado
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depende: linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic pero no está instalado
linux-image-5.15.0-37-generic : Depende: linux-modules-5.15.0-37-generic pero no está instalado
linux-image-generic : Depende: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-37-generic pero no está instalado
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depende: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-37-generic pero no está instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCV6g.png)

---

sudo apt-get install -f

dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic_5.15.0-37.39_amd64.deb (--unpack):
no se pudo crear `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic/include/config/BLK_DEV_RNBD_CLIENT.dpkg-new' (mientras se procesaba` ./usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic/include/config/BLK_DEV_RNBD_CLIENT'): No queda espacio en el dispositivo
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Comment: you /usr is an a separate partition. As far I know 5% on ext4 is reserved for root. Did you check emough inodes are free? `df -i /usr`

Comment: this is the output: df -i /usr
S.ficheros             Nodos-i NUsados NLibres NUso% Montado en
/dev/nvme0n1p9  500960   500400       560    100%      /usr

Comment: You were right, "nobody"; rm -rf /usr/src solved the problem!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: That was not a good idea 

Answer (score 0):

You're out of space on your drive, so there's no room to install the updates.

Your apt output indicates that you have an unused kernel that can be removed, so I would try `sudo apt autoremove` and see if that works. If not, you *may* be able to get away with deleting the oldest vmlinuz and initrd.img files out of `/boot`, but if you do this, **be careful to not reboot your system until you finish the upgrade successfully**, or you might end up having to go through a very interesting recovery procedure to get your laptop to turn on again.

Comment: No space error, despite having enough. Apparently that's not the problem... attached image.